# Rename Hive schema/database

Tags: hive, schema, database-schema

I'm using Hive 2.1.1 - and I need to rename one of my schemas.

I tried this command: `ALTER SCHEMA name RENAME TO new_name;`
But got this error back: `FAILED: ParseException line 1:13 cannot recognize input near 'name' 'RENAME' 'TO' in alter database statement`.

Does anyone know can I rename my schema?
Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive: Is it possible to rename an existing hive database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481237/hive-is-it-possible-to-rename-an-existing-hive-database)

Comment: It is still not supported by Hive. As a workaround, you can create a database with the new name and move all data (tables/views/etc) into it.